# How to add a new page based on page.html (similar to /groups or /dataset)

Tags: html, theming, ckan

I have installed and configured one CKAN 2.0.1 instance.

You can check it out here: http://www.caceresabierto.es; as you can see it is still very basic.

My problem is the following, I want to create the page http://www.caceresabierto.es/aplicaciones. I understand that there should be a method to heritage the layout and the basic theming from the main template (if I am not wrong is "base.html" or "page.html" in the 'templates' folder).

The point is: I have figured out how to modify www.caceresabierto.es/***dataset*** or www.caceresabierto.es/***groups***. But I don't know how to add a new route like www.caceresabierto.es/***aplicaciones*** that heritage from "page.html".

I suppose I will need to create a new HTML file in the 'template' folder and maybe modify setup.py or plugins.py...But I need some help to do it.

Any feedback would be great. Thank you.

Jesús Redondo.

---

Apologies for cross-posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload a new **aplicaciones.html** file to your **public_html** folder and then it will work. I don't think modifying any python files will be necessary.

If you want much of the page to look the same, you can start work on your new aplicaciones.html file by saving your old index.html file with a new name and modifying the relevant information.